# "package org.spongycastle.crypto does not exist" on one project, but works fine on another

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, spongycastle

I have downloaded both of these projects, with bitcoinj being rebased to the correct v0.11.3 tag:

https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet/
https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj

The bitcoin-wallet project gets bitcoinj 0.11.3 as a dependency on a maven repo and it works nicely. Then I changed it to use `<scope>system</scope>` to find the local bitcoinj .jar, which I built. Ever since I did this bitcoin-wallet complains with (with errors for each import and use of undefined symbols):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project wallet: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /.../bitcoin-wallet/wallet/src/de/schildbach/wallet/util/Crypto.java:[31,31] package org.spongycastle.crypto does not exist
```

This is odd because bitcoinj also imports `org.spongycastle.crypto...` and yet it builds correctly. I can't find any reference to spongycastle dependencies anywhere in the pom files for each. What is bitcoinj doing that bitcoin-wallet doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

BitcoinJ, had bouncycastle hidden with another dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.madgag</groupId>
        <artifactId>sc-light-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```